# PHP - Is there anyway to hide fopen warnings?

Tags: php, nginx, fopen, file-get-contents, ini

I have so far tried

Editing php.ini to `allow_url_open = on;`

I have tried placing `error_reporting(0)` at 0. I have tried `ini_set('display_errors', 0)` too. I still get a warning in my page. I also tried `@fopen` and `file_get_contents`... This is the code:

```
<?php 
/**
*   Image Detect - Do we have images on the CDN v2
**/
    $cdnurl="http://www.****-cdn.com/";
    $pid=$product_info['sku']; // database variable decalred earlier in page
    $oldfile="".$cdnurl."catwalk/movies/".$pid.".flv";
    $newfile="".$cdnurl."assets/".$pid."/v/".$pid.".swf";
    $combi=0; // out variable
    if(@fopen($oldfile,"r")===TRUE){
        $combi=1;
    } else {
        if(@fopen($newfile,"r")===TRUE){
            $combi=2;
        } else {
            $combi=3;
        }
    }

?>
```

> Warning : fopen(http://www.***-cdn.com/catwalk/movies/564_white.flv):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in
>   /var/www/www.sitedev.com/web/template.inc.php
>
> Warning :
>   file_get_contents(http://www.***-cdn.com/catwalk/movies/564_white.flv):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in
>   /var/www/www.sitedev.com/web/template.inc.php

These are the warnings... I have searched extensively and tried using `===FALSE` and `==FALSE` but I cannot hide the warning. I am aware the file does not exist but I just want it to skip, this code works on other servers and other cloud nginx servers that are the same setup.

```
phpinfo(); shows

allow_url_fopen     On      On
allow_url_include   Off     Off
error_reporting     no value    no value
```

Appreciate any help, my first question so go easy!

**   UPDATED   ********

I hope this is OK. The site says I can answer my own question.

The problem was script related. I use OpenCart Ecommerce platform and in that software there is something called - set_error_handler - this completely overrides everything else.

So in future since Opencart is bloated with these queries, visit /opencart root/index.php and find "set_error_handler('error_handler');" and replace and comment it out.

// Error Handler
//set_error_handler('error_handler');

Comment: "this code works on other servers"... could you just make a copy of the other servers?

Comment: I cannot clone the other servers because of many things :) thanks for the suggestion I did think of this but we can't just do that.

Comment: You _can_ answer your own question, but it is best to do so via the _Your Answer_ box, below. Once the time limit expires, please migrate your answer down there -- and add code formatting to make it legible. Thanks!

Comment: Someone voted my question up and then down! Why?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"So in future since Opencart is bloated with these queries, visit /opencart root/index.php and find "set_error_handler('error_handler');" and replace and comment it out."

It would be wiser to find the function `error_handler` which has been set as the error handler and alter the behaviour for the error type being hit in this case. Commenting out the line mentioned will cause your application to revert to PHP's standard error handling which may not be desired.